# DAG algorithms and Latin square problems

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, latin-square

Every Latin square corresponds to a ***directed acyclic graph*** with a lattice arrangement, and whose edges indicate order `(<)`.  For example:

[image: For example]
<sub>(source: [enjoysudoku.com](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/download/file.php?id=336))</sub>

I'm interested in determining which Latin squares have unique orderings, that is, whose corresponding DAG permits no other valid vertex labelling.

A valid labelling maintains uniqueness in rows and columns, and also satisfies the order relationships specified by the edges.

I can't find any references to labelling problems of this particular kind. Does this imply that the DAG structure is not particularly useful for this kind of analysis?

This relates to a study of uniqueness properties wrt Futoshiki puzzles.

Comment: This looks like more a question for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ... (I would flag it as such, but cs isn't in the list of allowed sites. Wtf?)

Comment: Ok, sorry if I posted an inappropriate question. I'll check out other options.